# Two articles in my php array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to make a webshop for an assignment and I can't figure out how to display that there are 2 of the same product in my checkout. This is my code I want to display something like: Article1 .. 2x Article2 ... 5x etc.

```
<?php
session_start();

//read out session with article numbers
$array = $_SESSION['mandje'];
echo '<center>';
echo '<h1> Uw mandje: </h1>';
echo '<table style="border: 2px solid black">';

//array that checks if there are two of the same article numbers
$mandje = array();

//read out array
foreach ($array as $artikel)
{
    echo '</br>';
    echo $artikel;
    if (in_array($artikel, $mandje)){
        //I need to display the article that i have multiple times here i guess
    } else {
        //getting the articles out of the database
        require ('config.php');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM mphp6_meubels WHERE artikelnr = $artikel";
        $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        while($meubel = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
            $video = $meubel['naam'];
            $nmr = $meubel['artikelnr'];
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td> <img src="Meubels/'.$video.'.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Meubel"></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
    //adding the article to array so i can check if there are multiple of the same articles in array
    $mandje[] = $artikel;
}
echo '</table>';
echo '</center>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group by `artikelnr` field.

```
foreach ($array as $artikel)
{
    require ('config.php');
    $query = "SELECT mphp6_meubels.*, count(*) as cnt FROM mphp6_meubels WHERE artikelnr = $artikel GROUP BY artikelnr";
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    while($meubel = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        $video = $meubel['naam'];
        $nmr = $meubel['artikelnr'];
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $artikel . '</td>';
        echo '<td> <img src="Meubels/'.$video.'.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Meubel"></td>';
        echo '<td> ' . $meubel['cnt'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```